# Spring: Error de conexión con Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

he creado un login con springBoot y postgres, pero cuando ingreso las credenciales me sale el siguiente error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error querying database. Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «postgres» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf) ### The error may exist in com/mitocode/javaweb/banca_digital/cliente/infrastructure/persistence/MyBatisClienteMapper.java (best guess) ### The error may involve com.mitocode.javaweb.banca_digital.cliente.infrastructure.persistence.MyBatisClienteMapper.findByDocumento ### The error occurred while executing a query ### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «postgres» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
> org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «postgres» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
>
> #### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «postgres» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)

He revisado las credenciales con las que me conecto a la DB y todo esta correcto, tambien rebvise el application.properties

gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó el mismo error después de crear un usuario en Postgres y luego intentando conectarme con las credenciales definidas (en un cliente de BD). Lo solucioné asignando el encoding:

```
ALTER ROLE "ROLE_NAME" IN DATABASE "DATABASE_NAME" SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8'
```

En mi caso UTF-8.

Si estas usando Hibernate también puedes revisar que juego de caracteres utilizas en estas propiedades:

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.charset
  spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding
```

¡Saludos!